# Does Mongo Atlas Online Archive count toward 4Tb storage limit for a cluster?

Tags: mongodb-atlas

Does Mongo Atlas Online Archive count toward 4Tb storage limit for a cluster?
I could not find any reference in the online documentation and would appreciate if someone can point to any official resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atlas Cluster storage is a separate entity from the storage that you occupy via Online Archive.
With Online Archive, you occupy the storage in AWS S3, while in a cluster you occupy the storage on the disk associated with that machine.
Due to this segregation, the [pricing](https://www.mongodb.com/pricing) is also different, i.e. you pay at a different rate for the data stored/transferred/processed than what you pay for the storage in cluster.